# Drupal PHP module won't uninstall

Tags: php, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I have a mix of pages with HTML and PHP content and had installed the PHP module on my Drupal 8.6.4 site.  Earlier today it was working fine and I edited several pages, selected PHP, and presto.  All was good.

But a couple hours ago, when I went to edit a page, the little "Text Format" pulldown wasn't selected (which was odd, as it had been on PHP before).  I went to reselect PHP and saw that's no longer an option.  Just the three default HTML text formats.

My PHP module was installed, but not wanting to post wantonly, I thought perhaps it needed to be REinstalled.  I uninstalled the module and it's no longer in the list of installed modules.

But the odd thing is I'm getting an error when I try to reinstall saying it's already installed.  So it's been uninstalled, but is now stuck:  won't reinstall, won't run because it's uninstalled.  Is there a flag in the database that I can truncate, perhaps, and get it to reupload the PHP module?  Why did the module vanish?  (or its functionality!).

Answer (score 0):

And the bozo award goes to me:  I'd re-installed the PHP module but somehow (it was late) overlooked the important step of enabling it.  No surprise, after that it worked fine and my pages returned to normal.